# How do I avoid registering a variable when a “when” condition is Not met?

Tags: ansible

How do I avoid registering a variable when a `when` condition is *not* met?

Comment: If you are talking about the `register` keyword at task level, answer is simple: you can't. It will always register the result of the task, e.g. `skipped: true` at the very least if your `when` condition evaluates to false. Your question is very general and does not give any example. What are you trying to do exactly? I suspect we are in an [x/y problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here... I suggest you [edit your question](/posts/68129048/edit) with more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible: How do I avoid registering a variable when a "when" condition is \*not\* met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34621799/ansible-how-do-i-avoid-registering-a-variable-when-a-when-condition-is-not)